# Error on !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))

Tags: c++-cli

This is the code in c++

```
List<String^> ^GetCodecs()
{
    List<String^> ^l = gcnew List<String^>;

    String ^s = gcnew String(Encoder_GetFirstCodecName());
    while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        l->Add(s);
        s = gcnew String(Encoder_GetNextCodecName());
    }

    return l;
 }
```

The error is on the line:

```
while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
```

On the String

The error/s are all about the String:

This is a warning:

```
Warning 1   warning C4832: token '.' is illegal after UDT 'System::String'
```

The errors:

```
Error   2   error C2275: 'System::String' : illegal use of this type as an expression
Error   3   error C2228: left of '.IsNullOrEmpty' must have class/struct/union
Error   4   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
Error   5   IntelliSense: type name is not allowed
```

How can I fix them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `IsNullOrEmpty` is a static function, you'd probably have to call it using the `::` operator:

```
while (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(s))
```